# How to use Python and HTML to build a desktop software?

Tags: python, html, css, desktop-application

Maybe my question is stupid but I still want to ask. 
I am always wondering whether I can use Python, HTML and Css to develop a desktop software. I know there are alrealy several good GUI frameworks like Qt, Tk and etc. But the various sources of HTML and JS frameworks are still attractive to me. I don't mean a software which is just like a web application where there is a frontend and Python acts as a server side language either. I mean use Python like other GUI frameworks. I can create widgets built by HTML and Css.
Dose there any framework have this function? I know there is *app.js* for Javascript. Or what I think is wrong.

Comment: So where does Python fit into this? Qt elements can be styled somewhat with a subset of CSS, but if you want to build a desktop app with HTML/CSS, why not just use JS and make a desktop webapp?

Comment: I know Qt is a perfect choice. I just want to know whether there is one more choice for me to develop desktop app using Python. @Blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [pyjs](http://pyjs.org).

### What is pyjs?

pyjs is a Rich Internet Application (RIA) Development Platform for both Web and Desktop. With pyjs you can write your JavaScript-powered web applications entirely in Python.

Answer (score 1):

CEFPython allows this by embedding the Chromium browser and providing python bindings to it:
https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/

~:  python example.py

brings up:

[image]